# Meteor multiple tab sharing state

Tags: node.js, meteor, sockjs

Users frequently open multiple tabs to my meteor app. Is there a way to get those tabs to share the same connection (state on the server) so that there isn't multiple redundant connections. I'm thinking about coming up with a package to do this myself, I'm wondering if anyone has given any thought to this. It should help with performance.

Comment: I doubt this make any sense in **meteor**. Since the way the data gets delivered to the clients is thorugh a custom `DDP protocol`, I am pretty much sure, there is no easy way to cache this data locally and preserve the reactivity of the `publish/subscribe` mechanism at the same time.

Comment: @apendua DDP is just a wrapper around sockjs? There are change events that should be possible to hook on. ebolyen's answer shows how you can pass around data on the client side. I think it's possible, can you explain in more detail why you don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) for this. This library does just that:

https://github.com/diy/intercom.js

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to share client-side data through localStorage (consider it a browser database).  It is also possible to share server-side data, commonly through database (MongoDB in case of meteor).  Network connection (instead of collection) is shared across tab automatically by the browser.

If you mean sharing *collection* (instead of connection), you don't need to do anything special to share them between tabs (clients).  Clients observing the same collection will see same data.

However, the convenience offered by Meteor has its cost.  One of it is that [each client has its own partial collection copy, thus it can use/waste lots of memory](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1821).

This is implementation details, and just like how JavaScript use/waste more memory and cpu then native code in exchange for convenience, there is not much you can do about it, at least not easily.

Update: As Harry noted, for real DDP connection 'sharing', it is possible to detect and disconnect new tabs and use localStorage to sync data from first tab, so that there is only one active connection.  However IMHO it would be quite a heroic feat.

Comment: `Network connection (instead of collection) is shared across tab automatically by the browser.` There are separate states for each of your tabs. This is not true in this context.

Comment: @Harry Sorry to confuse you, I don't mean Meteor connection by that .  Given how meteor (and web server) works in general, it is impossible to share Meteor (client) connection across tabs.

Comment: I don't believe this to be true. By sharing client side data you can disable ddp on certain tabs and force all your connections to go through 1 tab. Anyway thanks for the github link I finally understand what livedata does now, meteor is sheer insanity.

Comment: @Harry Yes, and the same insanity to everything web or programming.  You see, tab is like client's eyes, and a client can request multiple eye holes on the same door, and you can only block those that you don't want; you cannot combine the new eye holes with old one to fit in more eyeballs. What you are thinking is forcing the first eyeball to relay what it sees to other eyeballs. Can do, but IMHO this defeat the purpose of using Meteor, better just pop a warning and disconnect.

Comment: Thanks, weird metaphor. This is not just a meteor issue but an issue regarding any app with persistent client state. New connections has costs associated and creating a wrapper for the connection code is a one time change that doesn't really damage the ease of use in general development. But right now I'm not feeling too good about meteor.